# Get the month from epoch using moment

Tags: meteor, momentjs

In a Meteor server code:
`let t = Date.now();`
I need to get the month "0-11" from `t` using moment.js, Any idea what the syntax will be like? I could not find it in the docs. thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `moment().format()` and the format needs to be `MM` to get month in 0...12

```js
var t = new Date();
t.setMonth(t.getMonth() + 2);
var dt = moment(t).format('MM');
console.log(dt);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.js"></script>
```

**[DOCS](https://momentjs.com/docs/)**

Comment: It is the month not the hour, so HH needs to be MM, Also how can I add 2 to the month so that if it is January then I get 3 which is 1+2? thx

Comment: @FredJ. My mistake, got confused with some other question I was looking at the same time, corrected the error. Check the updated answer

Comment: My question needs to use `Date.now()` which is the epoch time, your answer used `new Date()` which is a date object. Will that be a problem?

Comment: I don't think that will be a problem